# Select all instance of a word in a rendered webpage

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, d3.js

I have a d3 word-cloud that launches an alert box when one of the cloud words are clicked. Instead of launching an alert box I want to highlight any matching instances of the clicked word in a corresponding div element `el`.

The handler is within an AngularJs directive so I have the context of the element within the immediate closure.

```
.on("click",function(v,i,l){
    console.log(
        el // [div.content ng-scope, ...
        v  // Object {text: "demo", ...
    );
    alert(v.text) // demo
})
```

I've done this before while building a search-box but I lost the code and completely forgot how I did it.

Comment: If I don't respond right away, I'm on my way out the door to take the little ones to a kiddie movie. Should be back in a few hours... This is really about finding/selecting text. I feel brain dead right now. This should be so simple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Or, if you want to use AngularJS, you can use a filter and binding:

```
Click: 
    <div style="border: red thin solid; width: 100px; padding: 10px;">
        <div ng-repeat="word in words">
            <a ng-click="$parent.selectedWord = word">{{word}}</a>
        </div>
    </div>
Selected:
    <div style="border: red thin solid; width: 100px; padding: 10px;">
        <div ng-repeat="word in words">
            <span ng-bind-html-unsafe ="word | highlightWord : selectedWord"></span>
        </div>
    </div>
Selected Word: {{selectedWord}}
```

and:

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.words = [
        "beer",
        "wine",
        "whiskey",
        "vodka",
        "gin",
        "rum"
    ];

    $scope.selectedWord = '';

});

app.filter('highlightWord', function() {
    return function(word, selectedWord) {
        if(word === selectedWord) {
            return '<strong>' + word + '</strong>';
        } else {
            return word
        }
    };
});
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/v4ueqx?p=preview

Note the use of ng-bind-html-unsafe in order to return the html unescaped from the filter. You could also accomplish this with a directive.

EDIT:

And if you want to highlight a word in a text block, the approach is very similar:

```
Click: 
    <div style="border: red thin solid; width: 100px; padding: 10px;">
        <div ng-repeat="word in words">
            <a ng-click="$parent.selectedWord = word">{{word}}</a>
        </div>
    </div>
Selected:
    <div style="border: red thin solid; width: 100px; padding: 10px;" ng-bind-html-unsafe ="text | highlightWord : selectedWord"></div>
Selected Word: {{selectedWord}}
```

and:

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.words = [
        "beer",
        "wine",
        "whiskey",
        "vodka",
        "gin",
        "rum"
    ];

    $scope.selectedWord = '';

    $scope.text = "blah blah beer blah blah blah wine blah blah blah whiskey blah blah blah vodka blah blah blah blah blah gin blah blah blah blah blah rum blah blah blah blah beer blah blah blah blah vodka blah blah blah vodka blah blah blah blah blah blah vodka blah blah blah blah";

});

app.filter('highlightWord', function() {
    return function(text, selectedWord) {
        if(selectedWord) {
            var pattern = new RegExp(selectedWord, "g");
            return text.replace(pattern, '<span class="highlighted">' + selectedWord + '</span>');
        } else {
            return text
        }
    };
});
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/wtxZme?p=preview

Comment: I'm trying to select a word from a paragraph, this would work if I wrapped each word in span. Since the content is generated, maybe I could get away with adding it to the entire paragraph and replacing the words in the filter function. Let me see if I can make your solution work.

Comment: +1 for the answer, it's a good approach. I'm still trying to figure out if I can use it. I'm searching a huge template, so i hate to think I'd have to add the filter to all these divs.

Comment: I'm looking for something like this. Still need to angular-ize it. http://jsfiddle.net/PwcGh/

Comment: You could create a directive, which would also have to be added to all of the divs...or you could over-ride the div element type with a directive, which could have unintended consequences.

Comment: This function actually lives in my "tag-cloud" directive. Its part of a d3 word cloud on my resume. I got it working on the entire template, but basically when you click a word, it highlights the words in the corresponding company section. I don't like the fact that it parses the DOM instead of the model and although I'm convinced there's a better way to do this, its clean and quick enough that I can move on.